# How to store timestamp with milliseconds in PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, time

I need to store timestamps in the format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS` (SSS standing for milliseconds) in a PostgreSQL database. Surely it would work as a text/or varchar, but I need to "work" with the timestamps (e.g. filter all instances prior a certain timestamp - considering milliseconds).
How would I do that in PostgreSQL?

Comment: then why other DB tags?

Comment: Do not store it as text or varchar...

Comment: Use `timestamp` data type in postgreql. I generally use `timestamp with timezone`. It will gives you timezone as well

Comment: If you want to get `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS` during query you can format it and will get in desired format.

Comment: Never ever stored timestamps (or dates or numbers) in a `varchar` column. Just don't

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name you are right it will ruin the features of `timestamp`.

Answer (score 51):

I know this is an old question, but I had a similar problem.

You can use the timestamp(n) field, with n equals the number of digits of precision to store on the date (timestamp(3) would give you millisecond precision)

**Example**

```
CREATE TABLE date_test (datetime timestamp(3) with time zone);

insert into date_test values(to_timestamp(1525745241.879));

select EXTRACT(epoch FROM datetime) from date_test;
```

**Note**: in current versions of postgres timestamp is stored as an integer, so it does not incur in floating point rounding issues

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, saved my some time.

Comment: I can't find what is the default precision but I assume it is timestamp(6) microsecond since I'm able to store microsecond timestamp without specifying the precision, anyone have a ref to this? Also does anyone have the maximum for this precision field?